# Print only the maximum value in the column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a script, I enter data in it, but there is one problem that I cannot solve. I have duplicate values. All because of the INFO peg. In the INFO column, I may have either nothing or some value. Then I only print the meaning (that is what I decided). But it can be when there are two courses, one less, and the other more, riding out only the maximum. Thank you for your help)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6edb8b040779522cca52802748bc3918
Now the answer is this

```
+ --------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| ID      | VALUE_NUMBER  | VALUE_STRING                         | INFO              |
+ --------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 4680828 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDENT |
| 4680704 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | MY_IDENT          |
| 4680828 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | MY_IDENT          |
| 4680704 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDEN  |
+ --------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

And I want to go like this

```
+ --------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| ID      | VALUE_NUMBER  | VALUE_STRING                         | INFO              |
+ --------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 4680828 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDENT |
| 4680704 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDENT |
+ --------+---------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I looked into your dbfiddle. I am sorry for you that you must work with key value tables, as I know they are a pain to work with. You are using outer joins, but they are partly flawed (`i` is actually inner joined because you put the citeria in `WHERE` instead of `ON`). Do you want outer joins or inner joins. Then you aggregate a lot (GROUP BY`) without actually getting any aggregates (`MIN`, `COUNT`, `SUM`, ...). You shouldn't do this. If you are getting undesired data or duplicate data, then find out why and prevent this instead of trying to remove them in the end.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for the comment, but I spent a lot of time giving this query, but didn't know why the answer was being duplicated, so I decided to group in order to solve the problem somehow.And since I have some experience with the oracle. then forced bato to ask here.Could you look at this link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=75a9e4dc3bd978f178707b36bc480a4d, and help me with these questions?))

Comment: I've posted an answer that may help you.

Comment: The duplicates stem from your unecessary join of rep to txn by the way. Both have two rows with transaction number 1578109515974 on which you join. So two rows each matching two rows. 2 x 2 = 4 rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I meant helping with https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7001352334ddc1c9fa9272b431aab270   To keep INFO the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregates (such as `max`) usually help:

```
select id, value_number, value_string, 
       max(info) as info                     --> this
from your_table
group by id, value_number, value_string;
```

Your query (from dBFiddle), fixed:

```
WITH txn
     AS (  SELECT TRANSACTION_VALUE_NUMBER,
                  READER_VALUE_STRING,
                  ID,
                  MAX (info) AS info
             FROM (  SELECT o.VALUE_NUMBER AS transaction_value_number,
                            i.VALUE_STRING AS reader_value_string,
                            o.id,
                            TRIM (
                                  v.VALUE_STRING
                               || ' '
                               || v.VALUE_NUMBER
                               || ' '
                               || x.VALUE_STRING
                               || ' '
                               || c.VALUE_STRING)
                               AS INFO
                       FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  o
                            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i ON o.parent = i.parent
                            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  v
                               ON     i.parent = v.parent
                                  AND v.KEY = 'truck1'
                            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  x
                               ON     i.parent = x.parent
                                  AND x.KEY = 'item_name'
                            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  c
                               ON     x.parent = c.parent
                                  AND c.KEY = 'truck2'
                      WHERE     i.key = 'reader'
                            AND i.VALUE_STRING =
                                   'aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25'
                            AND o.key = 'transaction'
                            AND o.value_number <> 0
                            AND TRIM (
                                      v.VALUE_STRING
                                   || ' '
                                   || v.VALUE_NUMBER
                                   || ' '
                                   || x.VALUE_STRING
                                   || ' '
                                   || c.VALUE_STRING)
                                   IS NOT NULL
                   GROUP BY o.id,
                            o.VALUE_NUMBER,
                            i.VALUE_STRING,
                            TRIM (
                                  v.VALUE_STRING
                               || ' '
                               || v.VALUE_NUMBER
                               || ' '
                               || x.VALUE_STRING
                               || ' '
                               || c.VALUE_STRING))
         GROUP BY TRANSACTION_VALUE_NUMBER, READER_VALUE_STRING, ID)
  SELECT rep.id,
         rep.VALUE_NUMBER,
         txn.reader_value_string AS VALUE_STRING,
         min(txn.INFO) info
    FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  rep JOIN txn ON rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number
   WHERE     LOWER (rep.key) = 'transaction'
         AND rep.value_number <> 0
GROUP BY rep.id,
         rep.value_number,
         txn.reader_value_string;
```

**[EDIT]**

Regarding comment you posted:

> VALUE NUMBER may be different but the INFO must be the same

If you apply `MIN` in its **analytic** form (and - thus - remove the whole `GROUP BY` clause), the last several lines (as well as the result) in your query will look like this:

```
 <snip>
 55    SELECT rep.id,
 56           rep.VALUE_NUMBER,
 57           txn.reader_value_string AS VALUE_STRING,
 58           min(txn.INFO) over (partition by txn.reader_value_string) info
 59      FROM iot  rep JOIN txn ON rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number
 60     WHERE     LOWER (rep.key) = 'transaction'
 61           AND rep.value_number <> 0;

        ID VALUE_NUMBER    VALUE_STRING                             INFO
---------- --------------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------
   4680828 1578109515971   aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25     95888137 MY_IDENT
   4680704 1578109515974   aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25     95888137 MY_IDENT

SQL>
```

**[EDIT #2]**

With new data on dbFiddle, would this help? Remove analytic function, indlude two `MIN`s (one for `REP.ID`, another for `TXN.INFO`):

```
 <snip>
 54    SELECT MIN (rep.id) id,
 55           rep.VALUE_NUMBER,
 56           txn.reader_value_string AS VALUE_STRING,
 57           MIN (txn.INFO) info
 58      FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION rep
 59           LEFT JOIN txn ON rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number
 60     WHERE     LOWER (rep.key) = 'transaction'
 61           AND rep.value_number <> 0
 62           AND rep.id NOT IN (SELECT o.id
 63                                FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o,
 64                                     IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION parent
 65                               WHERE     o.parent = parent.parent
 66                                     AND parent.key = 'reader'
 67                                     AND parent.VALUE_STRING !=
 68                                            txn.reader_value_string)
 69  GROUP BY rep.value_number, txn.reader_value_string;

        ID VALUE_NUMBER    VALUE_STRING                             INFO
---------- --------------- ---------------------------------------- --------------------
   4680704 1578109515974   aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25     95888137 MY_IDENT
   4680501 1578109515974   aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a26     95888138

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but this code is not universal. That is, if transactions 1578109515971 and 1578109515974 then your add-on is appropriate), but if transactions 1578109515974 and 1578109515974 you need to return to the code where min (txn.INFO) info. This code is also not suitable for the case when the table contains readers that have the same and different traction!

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c850aa0dff9d2d41cfc73905d77d5d2  In this version, your code does a double. In this version, your code does a double

Comment: See EDIT #2 I posted in the answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

Following query will give you the expected output.

```
select * from test where length(INFO) in (select max(length(INFO)) from test 
group by ID,VALUE_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I tried your example but it didn't work in my example)

Answer (score 1):

Aggregates (such as max) usually help

```
select * from your_table where INFO  =  (Select max(INFO) from your_table)
```

Comment: I tried your example but it didn't work in my example)

Answer (score 1):

Key/value tables are a pain to work with. The typical way to go about this is to use aggregation, so as to get the values combined in a row as if it were a row in a normal table.

```
with data as
(
  select
    parent,
    max(case when key = 'transaction' then value_number end) as transaction,
    max(case when key = 'reader' then value_string end) as reader,
    max(case when key = 'truck1' then value_number end) as truck1_number,
    max(case when key = 'truck1' then value_string end) as truck1_string,
    max(case when key = 'truck2' then value_number end) as truck2_string,
    max(case when key = 'item_name' then value_string end) as item_name
  from iot_stream_analytics_log_representation
  group by parent
)
select
  transaction,
  reader,
  trim(truck1_string || ' ' || truck1_number || ' ' || item_name || ' ' || truck2_string)
    as info
from data
where reader = 'aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25' and transaction <> 0
order by transaction;
```

This results in

```
+ --------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| TRANSACTION   | READER                               | INFO              |
+ --------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | MY_IDENT          |
| 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDENT |
+ --------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

which is two rows, because there are two matching entries (two parent values) in the table.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27b65b47d30eeae85098b8d32678688f

Comment: yes, this is a great option, but it should all be WITH WITH txn
      AS () because I have to use it then another query)

Comment: Usually you would not have concrete keys like 'truck2' and 'reader' in a query, because you'd use key/values in order to have the DBMS oblivious to them and only interact with them at a business level. Queries like your original query or mine, would then be generated by the UI dynamically. If you really need the same attributes in several queries, you should think about transfering them to real columns in a real table (e.g. tables `transactions(transaction_id, transaction_date)` and `transaction_items(transaction_id, item_id, amount)`).

Comment: ... And if you are not allowed to change the table design, then create views. In Oracle you can even create materialized views in order to improve access speed.